# NotifyIcon OnClick not firing

Tags: c#, winforms, onclick, notifyicon

I have assigned this:

```
// notifyIcon_Closed
            // 
            this.notifyIcon_Closed.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("notifyIcon_Closed.Icon")));
            this.notifyIcon_Closed.Text = "Ico";
            this.notifyIcon_Closed.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.notifyIcon_Closed_MouseClick);
            //
```

and then in my Form class I have:

```
private void notifyIcon_Closed_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
        }
```

The notifyicon is visible; however when I click it nothing happens.  I am so lost.  Am I overlooking something simple?

[image]

Comment: Did you put a break point in the notifyIcon_Closed_MouseClick to see if it's being activated at all?

Comment: Its not being reached, why is this though?

Comment: And you're positive the event is being added in the constructor/initialization?

Comment: Look at the image I just added to my post...

Comment: What happens if you assign it to Click instead?

Comment: Could you post the entire `NotifyIcon` code from designer.cs please.

Comment: I added it to my original post ^

Comment: That's not the designer code, it's just the designer UI.

Comment: Try adding `this.notifyIcon_Closed.Visible = true;` to it. If that's all the code then your notifyicon shouldn't be visible.

Comment: That's what in my designer.cs  file

Comment: I make it visible withing my code later; however, when it is visible, clicking it does nothing.

Comment: Given the code you have this should work. Are you reassigning the notifyicon anywhere in your code? If you go to your designer file and put the caret on notifyIcon_Closed, right click and click "Find all references", is there some code that might be removing the handler?

Comment: There is no NotifyIcon visible in the screenshot that you posted...

Answer (score 0):

notifyIcon should be placed in main application form

I've got the same problem and the reason is that notifyIcon was placed on control, not main form.